# program run, but wrong results.... is a program that find the missing side of a rectangle triangle and find its angles

Tags: c

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void pitagoras(float l1, float h);
void angulo(float l1, float l2);

int main() {
    float lado1, hipotenusa;
    printf("sea el triangulo del tipo ABC siendo C la hipotenusa con angulo opuesto c=90\n        y el angulo b opuesto al lado 1");
    printf("ponga la hipotenusa:\n");
    scanf("%f", &hipotenusa);
    printf("ponga el lado 1:\n");
    scanf("%f", &lado1);
    pitagoras(lado1, hipotenusa);
    angulo(lado1, lado2);
    return 0;
}

void pitagoras(float l1, float h) {
    if(l1 >= h) {
        printf("error, no es un triangulo rectangulo");
    }
    else {
        float l2;
        l2= sqrt(h*h - l1*l1);
        printf("el lado 2 es:%f", l2);
    }
}

void angulo(float l1, float l2) {
    float angulob, anguloa;
    angulob= atan(l1 / l2);
    anguloa = 180 - (angulob + 90);
    printf("los angulos a y b son:%f, %f", angulob, anguloa);
}
```

For some reason I keep getting 1 in `l2` no matter which number I use. How I can fix this?

Comment: What you posted cannot compile, `lado2` is not declared in `main`.

Comment: thanks now i get the correct lado2 i think that I can manage the other stuff, again thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan/

atan takes radians

http://www.mathinary.com/degrees_radians.jsp

radians = degrees * PI / 180